# How to redirect file URL's to another site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible to redirect file URL's? For example, I have a link to txt file on my server. For example:

www.mydomain.com/readme.txt

The domain will not host that file any more soon and I would need to redirect this link to some other location:

www.mydomain2.com/readme.txt

The problem is that the first link is part of some desktop applications and I cannot change the desktop applications but need to redirect the link. Is this possible? Maybe with .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using .htaccess personally:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^readme.txt http://mydomain2.com/readme.txt [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I created .htaccess and did as you specified but all I get is Internal Server Error.

Comment: Weird, tested it on the htaccess tester with no errors o.o is that the entirety of your htaccess file or did you add your own code too?

Comment: I just created a new file (.htaccess) and pasted this into. Of course, I only changed the destination domain. But maybe there is something wrong with my server..?

Comment: Thanks but still no luck. It's like Internal Server Error does not appears only if .htaccess is empty. Do I need to have some additional permissions, contact my hosting provider..?

Comment: The problem was in Options "+FollowSymLinks". My server did not accept this line and after I removed it redirect worked.